# where do I go to report an issue with "Date & Time"?

Tags: bug-reporting, timezone

I recently had to change time zone on my computer. I'm in Solomon Islands, where the capital city is Honiara. I selected "Pacific" as the "Region", and searched the "City" list for Honiara, but didn't find it. I finally clicked on the map about where Solomon Islands is, and it filled in "Guadalcanal" in the "City" list. Guadalcanal is the name of an island and a province, but NOT a city in the Pacific (it is the name of a village in Spain). It should be replaced with Honiara in the "City" list. Where do I report that, other than here...? I reviewed the "Report a bug" page, and this doesn't seem to rise to the level of a 'bug'

Comment: If that’s a bug, it goes [all the way back to the IANA time zone database](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Solomon_Islands) 

Comment: @guiverc: not really; I don't think this is a bug

Comment: @user535733: exactly, that's why I was asking where to go to report the issue

Comment: @matigo: thanks for that lead; the most helpful so far. I'll try to find a way to report it there. Note: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/solomon-islands, which lists "Honiara" as the "Example City". That's more consistent with what I would expect in "Date & Time".